# How to use Android ADT Translation Manager

Tags: android, internationalization, google-play, adt

How do I use the ADT Translation Manager (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#tmgr)? After I install it, there's a menu option to `Upload String for Translation`, but that tells me I don't have a translation project yet.

When I go to the Play Store to create a project, it requires me to upload files to get started, and I would have to finish the flow and pay in order for it to create the project.

How do I use the plugin to upload the files? I have a rather large project, and it would be an enormous pain to upload the files one at a time through the web tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that, but I manage my translation by my own.

transai - https://github.com/Jintin/transai

It's a command line tool I wrote to manage my Android & iOS text.
It can generate csv files from your strings.xml, and you can do translate according the csv file.
After you finish, you can transform it back to strings.xml.

It more readable for now IT man to help me do translate this way.
You can give it a try.

If you have any further question, you can leave issue to me.
Thank you.